# Where do includes go for templateURLs in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Sorry this will obviously be a beginner question.  I have Angular up and running fine within a Grails application.  Now I have defined a directive that is effectively a control needed.  This directive uses 'templateUrl' - that also works fine.

However, this is the simple part that I just don't know.  Where would I put includes to javascript libraries that are only needed by the directive?  That is, statements like:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

I have put them in the main page for now, but that doesn't seem quite 'right'.  These are dependencies of the directive, not of the page.  From a maintenance perspective, if that directive were ever removed due to changes, how would anyone know to remove the other links?
Note: my directive is already in an open  statement - if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a larger question of dependency management. There really are 3 routes for doing this:

1. Include it in the main `index.html` (like you did) and declare it as a dependency in your docs. Feel ugly? Sure. But it is how a lot of stuff is done.
2. Use requirejs http://requirejs.org It is a module loader, and so at least the code itself can explicitly declare its dependencies.
3. Use browserify http://browserify.org It is also a module loader, but following UMD/CommonJS, exactly like in node.

I started with #1, then #2 for a while, but recently shifted to #3. The files are cleaner, and using `npm` makes managing the dependencies far easier.

Answer (score 0):

Loading all external resources inside index.html is the common approach (SPA load all its resources once), but its not a must.

Inorder to achieve your goal you need to use external tool, we use RequireJS (Browserify is good as well) this way you can control the sources you load into the page.

Checkout this:

[RequireJS official site](http://requirejs.org/)

[Using RequireJS in Angular Applications](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-requirejs-angularjs-applications/)